# Mixing dispatch style throwing warning and couldn't dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Below is the first style to do a dispatch which is working fine

```
this.props.dispatch(functionInAction(someParam));

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component);
```

Below is another style of dispatch which should be working fine too

```
this.props.functionInAction(someParam);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { functionInAction })(Home);
```

Now I trying to mix the style to come up with something as below

```
this.props.functionInAction(someParam);
this.props.dispatch(functionInAction2(someParam))

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { functionInAction })(Home);
```

Immediately I'm getting `this.props.dispatch` is not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  If you supply your own `mapDispatch` function or use the "object shorthand" of an object full of action creators, then the default behavior of giving `props.dispatch` no longer applies.

See the [Redux FAQ entry on `props.dispatch` being made available to your component](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#why-dont-i-have-this-props-dispatch-available-in-my-connected-component).